# Use Passport.js with Postgres instead of MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, passport.js

I am trying to implement a login system within a PERN application. The problem I am having is that Passport is not exactly easy to understand and most tutorials out there (even the official docs) use MongoDB, so they utilize the findOne method to check if the user already exists.

That's the point at which I can't follow the tutorials anymore, since I don't know how to do that part with Postgres.

Would you help me implement Passport using PostgreSQL instead of Mongo or give me an idea how to do it?

Comment: You might want  to visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078839/installing-passportjs-with-postgresql

Comment: Hi. Yes, I saw that answer, but I decided to open a new thread because that answer is very old (2015). I figured there might be a more "modern" way of doing it.

Comment: IMHO the modern way is to use ORM such as sequelize.js, where you can follow the ORM query builder instead of DB specific query, and in long run, it will also help you to migrate from one DB to another with nearly little change.

Comment: Yes, I read about ORM's, but since I am trying to learn SQL, I am kind of forcing myself to avoid them. I guess it's still possible to do this without an ORM, right?

Comment: yeah, you do it without an ORM. In place of .findOne() you can use normal 'select' query.